# What should our FAQ contain?

Tags: discussion, top-7, site-attributes

Enter a single **FAQ (with answer)** per answer. Vote on the ones you like the best.

[Vote on other site attributes](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41/site-attributes)

Comment: Generic suggestion since I can't write out a nice entry at the moment: But if these recommendations / identification questions will keep popping up we should have some guidelines to how detailed it should be to be valid.

Comment: Wait, which FAQ are we talking about, the main or the meta?

Comment: What is the top-7 tag all about? (I've never seen it before this question landed on the front page)

Answer (score 10):

### What kind of questions should I *not* ask here?

`Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion.` **This is not a discussion board**, this is a place for questions that can be answered!

If you want to talk about the site itself, please don't do it here. Visit our [meta-discussion site](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/) where you can talk about things like what questions are appropriate, what tags we should use, suggest a feature, or generally discuss how {site name} works.

If your question is about ...

- **Developing a game or writing modifications to a game**, ask on {game-dev}.
- **Non-video games (such as board game or card games)**, ask on {board-games} or {card-games}
- **General computer software or hardware troubleshooting**, ask on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Additionally, avoid asking questions that only apply for a short amount of time. We want to create a knowledge base here, so questions of what the newest version of X, or the release date for Y, are generally not considered helpful.

Comment: Another kind of question we should avoid that I'm starting to see occur distressingly more often is "Why was this feature designed into the game"? Such as http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2134/why-do-you-need-a-ss-for-some-korean-games and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1625/why-is-it-a-good-idea-to-have-a-separate-health-and-armor-counters-in-first-perso. It's both off-topic and nothing but conjecture.

Comment: [Not all game mods really are game-dev material](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/544/do-map-editor-questions-belong-here). Also this conflicts with "software tools commonly used by gamers".

Answer (score 6):

### What kind of questions can I ask here?

{site name} is for `knowledgeable and enthusiast gamers`, people who have a passion for video games regardless of platform. We feel the best questions ask about a concrete problem encountered while playing a **specific video game**, but if your question generally covers ...

- game strategies and hints
- software tools commonly used by gamers
- matters that are *unique* to gamers
- any kind of problem that makes you stop playing

... then you're in the right place to ask your question!

Please do look around to see if your question has already been asked (and maybe even answered!) before you ask. It's also perfectly fine to ask and 
answer your own question, as long as you pretend you're on [Jeopardy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeopardy!): phrase it in the form of a question.

Comment: One should keep in mind that "finishing a game and needing a new one" is not a "problem that makes you stop playing".

Comment: @Grace to be honest that 4th bullet is a bit too creative anyway, I just wanted to add something that will fit the "spirit of the site". Let's say that whoever wants to remove the 4th bullet should upvote your comment :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is appropriate, since it's pretty much implied with this kind of site, but below "Be Honest" I would like to add

### Be Helpful

We all share the fun hobby of playing games.  We aren't all great, but we come to the site to get help and become better.  Please provide answers that will be useful in addressing the question.  We want this site to have useful information for future visitors!

Perhaps if someone finds it useful for the faq they could edit it to sound better :)

Answer (score 2):

## What is an acceptable answer?

A good answer is one that seeks to fully address the question asked. The StackExchange network is not a forum. Posting answers that are structured as such will most likely result in downvotes or a removal. Examples of this include:

"Im having this problem too. I heard there was a fix coming. I haven't seen one yet though :("

Answers should not rely solely on links to external sources. A corner stone within the StackExchange network is that the information should be available *on the the site* and not on a third party site. If the information stays within the network it can be edited and kept current while peer reviewed.

Extraneous information should be avoided. Such as including "Edit:" within the post when editing. StackExchange has its own feature marking edits. Adding "Thank you" at the end of posts are frowned upon and will most likely be edited away.

Comment: This is an attempt at wording a section for "What is an acceptable answer?". I believe the section is important and can pointed at when new users post answers that does not measure up. I believe that this is a nicer way than just being met by down votes(or at least explaining them) because you did not read the FAQ. Which in itself is not such a big deal as long as you are willing to learn.

Comment: +1 For trying to give new users a roadmap to get good feedback from the community.  Keep it up, there is plenty of room for improvement.

Answer (score 1):

**Which games can I ask questions about?**

You can ask questions about any PC or Console game ever created.  From *Asheron's Call* to *Zelda II: Adventures of Link* and from *Pong* to the game that was just released

**Note:** I'm open to other from, to suggestions, just wanted something with an 'A' and an 'Z'.

Answer (score 1):

## What is the Community Wiki?

Some questions cannot be satisfied with a single answer. They can require discussion to arrive at a consensus or require collaborative effort to assemble a list of satisfying options. These kinds of questions should be put into the Community Wiki. Essentially, the Community Wiki is the community, as distinct from any individual.

### Questions that belong in the Community Wiki:

- What tools are there to capture gameplay video?
- What games are similar to X?

### Questions that *don't* belong in the Community Wiki:

- What's the maximum level in [Game X]? - *normal question*
- What's the best MMO out there? - *subjective, doesn't belong on this site at all*

### What is different about the Community Wiki?

- With a reputation of 100 points you can edit posts in the Community Wiki.
- You do not gain any reputation for contributions to the Community Wiki.
- Posts in the community wiki do not display user signatures.

Comment: Wait, questions can be put in the Community Wiki? I thought only answers could. How do you do that with questions?

Comment: We can't anymore, it requires moderator intervention. Only answers can be marked as CW by users. We really don't use CWs on this site at all as we [try to avoid questions that require extended discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/380/27134)

Comment: Your examples in "Questions that belong in the Community Wiki", especially the second one, are not the sort of questions we allow.  For the most part, we don't really use Community Wiki at all.

Comment: Community Wiki should not be used to get around prohibited questions. List questions such as "What games are similar to X?" are not allowed, Community Wiki or not.

Comment: I think that the definition should be focused more on how it works rather than why. For example, mention that answers can be attributed to the Community Wiki after creation and not just at. If you've earned rep from an answer then attribute it to the CW, do you keep the rep or no? The emphasis on questions seems irrelevant since it has been made clear that non-moderators cannot attribute questions to the CW, while this definition is being addressed to new users

Answer (score 0):

### Can I add a signature to my questions and answers?

No, because we take care of that.

*Insert site name here* always puts a box at the end of all of your questions and answers, showing off your avatar, reputation and badges. This is your signature. You can customize it by [changing your avatar](http://www.gravatar.com/).

Answer (score -3):

Under the question

### What kind of questions should I not ask here?

I think it should be worth adding that before asking a potentially hazardous question, people should ask themselves: "Does this encourage gaming amongst all gamers?"  That's the real rule of thumb for what should and should not be allowed.

Comment: I don't understand that rule of thumb. Gamers don't need encouragement to game, and I don't believe that the questions asked here should attempt to do so.. How does asking a question encourage anything?

Comment: When discussing issues related to: modifying games, abandonware, and other legally grey issues, it helps to have a rule of thumb on which to rely.  I really think this is ours.

Comment: I'm seeing where you're going with this, and I agree with it, but "Does this encourage gaming amongst all gamers" is a very vague phrasing. I would not associate such a statement as being used to block legally grey issues (since excluding the legal issues they *are* about gaming).

Comment: @Grace I think issues concerning the law should be blocked separately.  On the subject of: should we share abandonware websites I answer that question by asking myself "Does this encourage gaming amongst all gamers?"  Companies aren't making money off these games, so there is no loss to future games, so the answer is yes.  By comparison if the subject was Piracy, this would cost game makers and thus reduce the number of new games, so the answer would be no.  This separates these issues nicely. http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/266/should-we-allow-links-to-abandonware-game-sites

Comment: "encouraging gaming amongst all gamers" is rather undefined as a statement by itself. It's not a very concrete statement that is universally understood. When I think about "abandonware", for example, I don't think it encourages the act of gaming. It's no different to me than how a store might sell a specific game at a discount. That opens up the window for more people to play the game, but to the community as a whole it's not exactly encouraging the act for all gamers. What defines a question as "encouraging" is slightly subjective.

Comment: @Grace I think the issue you're having is not that it's undefined, but that you keep trying to apply it to individuals instead of the community.  You point out that some individuals benefit, where as others do not.  This is irrelevant.  What matters is what the effect on the community is.  A sale increases the community, this is a valuable thing.  Depriving revenue for game makers is not.

Comment: No, I'm not concerned with my own application of the statement. I'm concerned that the statement, in its undefined and vague state, can be interpreted very differently by anyone - it's a subjective rule. And that's not very clear when we're trying to promote it as something the average user should be doing.

Comment: For example, I applied it when I was analyzing http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/361/whats-the-stance-on-mods-to-pc-games/362#362. My internal monologue went something like {Does making illegal patches to change the music of a game "encourage gaming amongst gamers"? Well, it doesn't cost the game makers like piracy does - the people already bought the game. It also lets the community enjoy the game more by allowing a level of customization. I guess that could be a yes.}. Notice how I'm following only the guidelines you had pointed out in your earlier comments. (cont.)

Comment: Those guidelines are all I can go by, and it's still not very clear to me, and while I'm not positing myself as a universal understander, I know that we're going to have other users confused by the statement, who will have to take up the reigns for themselves to decide what it means to 'encourage gaming amongst gamers'. Which, to me, is antithetical to a rule of thumb we want to advertise for all of our users to follow.

Comment: @Grace I would argue that the question "Does making illegal patches to change the music of a game" is a good example of the effectiveness of this guideline.  You came to much the same conclusion I did.  Though my thought process was: "Does this mod hurt anyone else trying to play the game?"