# Dual-posting on gaming and gamedev

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

What is the intended policy for questions like [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3358/best-way-to-test-simple-cases-in-games)? Gamers have opinions on them as well, and game-*dev* vs gam-*ing* sites can be a fine line. Would it be reasonable to dual-post such things? Surely, there will be more of these in the future, as the site grows. Good to ask now so we can have an intention for the site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact that gamers can have an opinion on game development doesn't make it on-topic here, as we have basically established [over here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/game-design-questions-on-topic-or-off-topic). We're not here to catch all questions of interest to gamers - we're here to catch questions for solving problems that gamers have. And a game design problem is one that is a problem that game developers have.

Consider that if I design a web application that is designed for programmers to use, I shouldn't be asking what people on Stack Overflow think about it. Not only is it a discussion poll, but there's no actual programming problem that I need solving.

So don't dual post. Just post it on the other site.

Comment: I guess in the near future will have a "belongs on game dev" close reason with migration

Comment: @Juan Ideally, we will

Comment: Jeff said there will be *some* migration between sites (that makes sense to)

Comment: I'm aware. The "ideal" part is it being a very near "near future".