# Closed "voice chat apps" question

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I am not sure why https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2752/pc-voice-chat-software-closed was closed... our [leading FAQ proposal](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226/what-should-our-faq-contain/379#379) lists that questions regarding software tools which are commonly used by gamers are okay.

It's true that software like Fraps or Ventrilo can be used for many thing which aren't games; but it seems to me that they are still something commonly used by gamers, not to mention that I believe the overwhelming majority of Fraps and Ventrilo users are gamers.

And in any case, if that was closed, I'm not sure why [How can I record demos of my gameplay?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-record-demos-of-my-gameplay) remains open...

Comment: As Grace said, it's not the fact he's asking about a "software tool", it's the fact that it's subjective and doesn't have a definite answer

Comment: I disagree. The recording question is asking how to do something specifically -- He wants to record a Gaming session. The PC Chat question is asking for popular software, which is totally subjective and doesn't seem to have a point other than to produce a list of said software.

Comment: oh, you deleted your comment :@

Comment: @Juan: you disagree with what? ;)

Answer (score 3):

The question you picked as an example strikes me odd, because the voice chat question is asking about "Popular choices" (subjective, the reason we closed and what I think I voted on), while the recording question is asking "How do I do this". The only thing they have in common is the topic of technology that is accessory to a game - and I'm going to believe that no one voted to close it based off of that (because indeed, we do cover technology related to gaming).

This *specific* voice chat question itself also strikes me as being like https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/804/what-food-drink-helps-fight-fatigue-while-gaming-closed - the question is no different than if you were to ask a similar question about what PC chat tools are popular among big businesses for coordinating meetings. But I didn't vote on that, to my recollection.

Comment: Interesting about about the "popular choices" vs the "how do I do this" question. The 2nd one can indeed have an accepted answer ("it worked for me"), while the 1st one really can't.

Answer (score 0):

I think Juan Manuel sums it up pretty well in his comment:

> The way this question is written invites for subjective or a list of answers. If you could rephrase it to ask a specific question with a definite answer as per the FAQ, it would be great and could get re-opened.

Comment: Yes, I wrote that before seeing this question here. I think Grace addresses the subject fully in [this answer](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reopen-voice-chat-apps/601#601)

Answer (score 0):

While I understand that the community wants a certain level of subjectivity, I don't think it is necessary to quite so rigorous with close votes. I believe in this instance a simple community edit would have sufficed.

I also don't see a problem with "inviting a list of answers". Some questions cannot be answered with one ultimate truth but that doesn't make them any less relevant.

Comment: What do you suggest we actually edit it into?

Comment: Yes. The tool is there. Why shouldn't it be used?

Comment: ...no, what I'm asking is, _what_ should we edit it into? We have the tool, but what should the end question be? I want to know how you would transform this subjective poll into a valid question.

Comment: Editing works for something like [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/2854/revisions), not (like @Grace said) to turn a poll into a question

Comment: OK. After lots of searching I finally found out what this community wiki is all about. Now I understand a lot better what you folks are complaining about. I guess all we need now is a way to turn another persons question into a community wiki post. If such questions can have their place there then I can live with that.