# Add a link to The Bridge chatroom for Game Recommendations in the FAQ

Tags: feature-request, game-recommendations, site-faq, help-center

Because [The Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) is an acceptable place to discus Game Recommendation questions, should the [faq](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/faq) be updated to include a link saying where to discuss it, rather than to the proposed 'Game Rec' site that is *still* in the commit stage?

Answer (score 2):

Following a [larger discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13489/28182) around how we can better help users that visit our site, Arqade now has a community [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) question for suggesting good places to go for recommendation questions (that are off-topic on Arqade):

[My request for recommendations was closed as off-topic. Where can I ask for help instead?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13548/28182)

Please feel free to add fresh answers to this FAQ post if you know of any other/new places that accept these types of questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to cover this partially [in our FAQ rewrite](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1820/revisions-of-the-gaming-site-faq-on-what-we-can-actually-ask-about), which I expect to completely abolish having game-rec get its own section and instead just be grouped with a cluster of "Do Not" items.

The problem with advertising the Bridge is that you need at least 20 reputation in order to chat there. This makes it less than ideal to direct new users there, who most likely do not have the sufficient reputation. I'm thus not really inclined to consider advertising our chat room right on the FAQ itself.

Comment: Well, then perhaps they should first get 20 rep before being able to ask for it

Comment: @IvoFlipse > That seems like it could be a deterrent to new users to me.