# My request for recommendations was closed as off-topic. Where can I ask for help instead?

Tags: discussion, faq, closing, game-recommendations

I posted a question asking for recommendations of games, consoles, or other hardware or software, which was closed as off-topic for one of the reasons explained [in this FAQ](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/so-what-actually-is-a-game-rec). Is there anywhere else I can ask for recommendations and suggestions?

---

This FAQ is part of a follow-up to [this proposal](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13490/143571) in our 2019 Community Check-in. Please post one suggestion per answer, stating any relevant information such as how to use it or the rules of its community, and whether it applies to game recommendations, hardware recommendations, or software recommendations.

Answer (score 14):

## The Gamingsuggestions subreddit on Reddit

https://www.reddit.com/r/gamingsuggestions/

This is a Reddit community focused specifically on suggesting games to play based on criteria given by the user. It just requires a free reddit account to use.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I can't access it.

Comment: @Scratch I'm not sure if it's relevant... if you suffer from a nationwide ban on the site, perhaps, but if you just mean "I'm at work and this is blocked", well, the solution is just 'don't browse gaming content while at work' :-)

Answer (score 10):

## The Bridge

If you have at least [20 reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat), you're welcome to join us in [The Bridge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge), Arqade's main chat room. Most of the regulars have played quite a few games, and might be able to suggest a game, piece of software, or hardware according to your needs.

Remember that [our Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies and, since this is a chat room, messages can get lost in the flow. Don't repeat your question too quickly if you don't receive an answer, but it's fine to ask again after a few hours in order to reach different people who might live in different timezones.

Answer (score 8):

**Video Game Recommendation Engine**

https://apps.quanticfoundry.com/recommendations/gamerprofile/videogame/

If you are looking for recommendations on what to play, you can give this engine 3 or more other video games that you enjoyed and its algorithm will find you plenty of similar titles! And it's free with no sign up!

Answer (score 6):

Arqade is not a forum where you just talk, but you could use basically any forum for this or similar questions.

I recommend

### [Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/)

It's a huge shop. Each game there has relevant discussion. Find a game you like, navigate to the general discussion forums, and ask "What are other games similar to this I can play?" Such questions are common.

Another option: Steam shop pages have suggestions with similar games at the bottom. This way you don't even need to ask anyone, just inspect each similar game yourself and you may find a good one.

Answer (score 5):

## [Steam's Interactive Recommender](https://store.steampowered.com/recommender/76561198053067330)

A new release by Valve, the Interactive Recommender analyzes games played by Steam users who have played the same games as you, trying to find games you might enjoy, given that they were enjoyed by people with similar tastes. It is, of course, limited to Steam games, and can only provide suggestions based on games you have played on Steam.

Answer (score 3):

## r/cade

For recommendations about arcade gaming hardware / diy

https://www.reddit.com/r/cade