# Why is my question closed and marked as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have big doubts and competency about closing my question. [How can I find more old-school players from Kazakhstan?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/394430/how-can-i-find-more-old-school-players-from-kazakhstan) Please re-open again.

Comment: Welcome to the site Mysyk! While I understand that having your question closed is frustrating, it's not intended to be a personal attack. Unfortunately not all questions work well within our Q&A format, and so as stated already by  multiple users, recommendation questions are outside the scope of Arqade.  I'd also encourage you to [review our Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) and take the [site tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 11):

The rule states: Questions that ask for **recommendations of games, servers, software, or hardware** are off topic.

I'm not sure how many people need to tell you that your question doesn't follow our rules. Your question is quite literally shopping for recommendations on finding players, and you've tried to bend the rules by slapping some games in your question. Our rules can't encompass every possible question format, but just because the rule doesn't *read* like it applies to your question, it still does apply. You are asking for recommendations on connecting with players. To quote:

> I posted my request on every Kazakhstan-related websites, forums, blog platforms and whatever.

This is not related to gaming. Kazakhstan is not a game, and Kazakhstan-related websites are not games either.

> Do I need to do special advertising?

This specifically reads as asking for a recommendation of some service that would connect you with people, which is off topic.

---

The ruling is sound. Take this as a lesson for what questions are accepted on our site, and familiarize yourself with our other rules so you can contribute your best. Additionally, the rule contains information on [external sources that can potentially be used to find what you need.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13548)

Answer (score 8):

I agree that this question should be closed:

## Reason

In the [Tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour):

> Ask about...
>
> - Gameplay strategies and tactics
> - Puzzle solving or obstacle clearing
> - Game mechanics and terminology
> - Plot and characters in games
> - Game-specific hardware and utilities
>
> Don't ask about...
>
> - Anything not directly related to gaming
> - Requests for game identification or recommendations
> - Questions that are primarily opinion-based, speculative, or gossipy
> - Questions about pirating games, or support for a game you've pirated
> - Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long -answer

- **Does this question ask about gameplay strategies and tactics?** No.
- **Does this question ask about puzzle solving or obstacle clearing?** No.
- **Does this question ask about game mechanics and terminology?** No.
- **Does this question ask about plot and characters in games?** No.
- **Does this question ask about game-specific hardware and utilities?** No.

So your question doesn't seem to ask something that is within the scope of the criteria that is described in the Tour. Now let's look at what you *shouldn't* ask.

- **Does this question ask about anything not directly related to gaming?** Yes. Finding players is **not** directly related to gaming. While I do agree that having a good community makes your experience better at gaming, it is **not** directly related to gaming.
- **Does this question primarily opinion-based, speculative, or gossipy?** Yes. This question will lead to a lot of opinion-based answers since the question doesn't have a "right" answer. Person A could come in and say that place X is all OG players, person B could come in and say that place Y has the best old-school,... This question also leads to a lot of gossiping.
- **Does this question has too many possible answers?** Yes, because as I said, there are a lot of places to find the OG player.

Answer (score 5):

I'd point you at the [help page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and remark, in particular that it doesn't really include the 'social' elements of gaming, like finding a local community. While its not explicitly contraindicated, its not within the scope of the site.